# How to Sort a List of Objects by dictionary value?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, lambda

How would I sort this by a chosen dictionary value in Person?

Example: Order List of "Person" by "cars" value descending.

Is that possible with one of those fancy lambda/linq equations?

```
public class People 
{
    List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> cars { get; set; } 
    public Dictionary<string, string> houses { get; set; } 
    public Dictionary<string, string> banks { get; set; }
}

................

People people = new People();

people.Persons = new List<Person> 
{
    new Person 
    {
        cars = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "volvo", "340050" }, { "bmw", "50545000" } }, 
        houses = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "mansion", "100040000" },{ "cardboard box", "112" } },
        banks = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "swiss", "12500330000" }, { "camen", "12000000" } }
    }, 
    new Person 
    {
        cars = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "volvo", "34023200" }, { "bmw", "5003300" } }, 
        houses = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "mansion", "1000330000" },{ "cardboard box", "277" } },
        banks = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "swiss", "12500044000" }, { "camen", "12000000" } }
    }, 
    new Person 
    {
        cars = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "volvo", "3554000" }, { "bmw", "50023200" } }, 
        houses = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "mansion", "1006600000" },{ "cardboard box", "244" } },
        banks = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "swiss", "125000544000" }, { "camen", "12000777000" } }
    }
};
```

**EDIT / EXAMPLE RESULT:**

The result would be a new or reordered list based on a value contained in the dictionary of each Person

Person -> cars -> { "volvo", "34023200" }
Person -> cars -> { "volvo", "3554000" }
Person -> cars -> { "volvo", "340050" }

The new or reordered List would look exactly like this:

```
people.Persons = new List<Person> 
{
    new Person 
    {
        cars = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "volvo", "34023200" }, { "bmw", "5003300" } }, 
        houses = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "mansion", "1000330000" },{ "cardboard box", "277" } },
        banks = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "swiss", "12500044000" }, { "camen", "12000000" } }
    },
    new Person 
    {
        cars = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "volvo", "3554000" }, { "bmw", "50023200" } }, 
        houses = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "mansion", "1006600000" },{ "cardboard box", "244" } },
        banks = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "swiss", "125000544000" }, { "camen", "12000777000" } }
    },
    new Person 
    {
        cars = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "volvo", "340050" }, { "bmw", "50545000" } }, 
        houses = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "mansion", "100040000" },{ "cardboard box", "112" } },
        banks = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "swiss", "12500330000" }, { "camen", "12000000" } }
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by cars?  Car names?

Comment: Each person contains a dictionary of cars and their values. How can I sort each person by that?

Comment: By what?  You have a dictionary, key or value?

Comment: SOrry, I'll add some example output right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a nifty trick; basically, a Dictionary can be thought of as a List of KeyValuePair<> objects.

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
foreach(var item in myDictionary)
// item is a KeyValuePair<int, string>, enumerated in order of their insertion into the dictionary
```

Now that it is in a list, it's easy to sort via LINQ:

```
Dictionary<int, string> sample = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
   { 1, "Sample" },
   { 2, "Another Sample" }
};

var orderedList = sample.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Of course, the bigger problem is why you would need to sort and order a Dictionary - that's not exactly an operation that is really grouped with the concept of a dictionary (it's more for quick access of specific elements via a specified key). The problem description you write about seems odd; you can order the cars for a specific person, but are you trying to find each car from each person ordered by value?

That's easy to do as well:

```
List<PersonCarDetails> allStuff = new List<PersonCarDetails>();

foreach(var person in persons)
   allStuff.AddRange(person.Cars.Select(x => new PersonCarDetails { PersonId = person.Id, CarName = x.Key, CarId = x.Value }).ToList());

 // allStuff now contains a list of PersonCarDetails, and then you can order that:

 var orderedList = allStuff.OrderBy(x => x.CarId).ToList();
```

Comment: I was having difficulty explaining my problem. I don't mean to order the dictionaries. I mean to order List<Person> by a dictionary value in each Person.

Comment: How would you choose which element of the dictionary to sort by? Example, you're say comparing Person 1 to Person 2. What component of Person 1's car dictionary are you comparing to what component of Person 2's car dictionary? Dictionaries are not ordered collections of data.

Comment: I can access the list like this `foreach (Person p in people.Persons)
 {
  string carValue = p.car["volvo"]; 
 }`. The dictionary isn't an ordered collection, but a list is. I just wanna sort all Person by a dictionary value in each Person.

Comment: I added an example output to my question area earlier.

Comment: If you want to sort the persons list by a required dictionary element, you can do that. `var people = people.Persons.OrderBy(x => x.Cars.First(kv => kv.Key == "volvo").Value)`. Note that this code will blow chunks if there is no key with the value "volvo" in the person's car dictionary.

Comment: man, that looks really good... I can't test it yet though. The compiler is telling me this `'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>'`. I added `using System.Linq.Expressions` to usings. Not sure what's going on. I'm gonna try to find an example program with lamba as google examples so tell me anything.

Comment: You should be using System.Linq; System.Linq.Expressions is a different set of code.

Comment: That works, thanks, testing now. I got the expressions thing off some msdn lambda page.

Comment: Ok, that works pretty good. There is a small problem though. I have values ranging from $9 billion to $44 billion. For some reason it orders them like the following (using OrderByDescending): `$9b, $44 -> 10b`. Why would the $9b place in front like that. It should just be `$44b -> $9b`.

Comment: Are you converting to a number? For a string comparison, that's working fine (the second character '9' is greater than '4', so it's ordered first in a by descending operation)

Comment: ahh k, so it's doing that because they are strings? How would I convert to an int in that statement for proper ordering?

Comment: int.TryParse OR int.Parse. Make sure you get rid of the currency symbols though.

Comment: Thanks again! Here is the complete solution: `var people = people.Persons.OrderBy(x => Int64.Parse(x.cars.First(kv => kv.Key == "volvo").Value));`. I have to say that is the most loosely written code I've ever seen in C#. Like how x and kv aren't predefined and such. THANKS!!

Comment: noob learning here: it's hard to read and fully understand when there 'var' -keyword is there: any ideas how would the above answer look if the variable types were explicitly declared?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean sort by the number of cars owned by the person

```
var result = Person.OrderByDescending(x => x.cars.Count);
```

If you mean sort by the first (sorted by name) car name owned by the person

```
var result = Person.OrderByDescending(x => x.cars.Keys.OrderBy(y => y.Key).FirstOrDefault());
```

If you mean sort by the first (sorted by number) car number owned by the person

```
var result = Person.OrderByDescending(x => x.cars.Keys.OrderBy(y => y.value).FirstOrDefault());
```

An example output would be good to clarify what actually you want to sort by, since cars is a list, rather than just an element.

---

Based on the examples you provided this might just do the job for you:

```
var result = Person.OrderByDescending(x => x.cars.Values.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Added example output as requested. Also looking at your examples now. Thanks.